# How to run node.js script without a file, from Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm generating a node.js script inside a Perl program, and I want to run that through node.js, as a JavaScript interpreter. How canO run the node in `$script` without writing it to disk and then calling node, afterwards capturing the output.

I'm using the `system` command, which I think is good for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [IPC::Run](http://p3rl.org/IPC%3a%3aRun) or [IPC::Open3](http://p3rl.org/IPC%3a%3aOpen3).

```
use strictures;
use IPC::Run qw(run);
use autodie qw(:all run);

my $in = '… JavaScript goes here …';
my $out;
run ['node'], \$in, \$out;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `open` instead of `system`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(FOO, "|node");
print FOO "console.log('hello world');";
```

Or if you don't need to do it from inside the perl script, just from your shell:

```
$ ./myscript.pl | node
```

Where `myscript.pl` exits after printing the javascript code

Comment: but i need to get the output of the scripts and then process the next one.